# PHP Child class self:: targets to parent

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static

I've got parent Class:

```
class Parent {

    public static $registered = array();

    public static function register($name){
        self::$registered[] = $name;
    }

}
```

and then I've got child Class that extends Parent.

```
class Child extends Parent {

}
```

Then I call

```
Child::register("foo");
```

and I do

```
var_dump( Child::$registered );
```

but its empty. (item was added to array of Parent and I wanted it to be added to array of Child)

Is it possible so self:: of parent function will be 'taken' by child classes too?

**(I want it to be static, I dont want to initialize objects)**

http://codepad.org/q9ujGiyM

Comment: Does your Child also have a `public static $registered = array();`... if so, why are you overriding the Parent's public property of the same name? That just seems pointless. But use `static` instead of `self` to reference the child's rather than the parents

Comment: What PHP version are you using? What you posted works for me in PHP 5.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with PHP 5.0.5 what you posted works.

As you can verify on [3v4l](http://3v4l.org/M9BGZ), for these versions it correctly outputs

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

So the best answer would be: upgrade your PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try `static::$registered[] = $name` instead of `self::$registered[] = $name`.

Comment: Works the same for me so its still targeting parent.